# Ember - How to get route model inside route action

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is it possible to access route model inside route action?

I am passing multiple objects inside a route model to template,

```
 model: function() {
    return {
        employeeList : this.store.findAll("employee"),
        employee : Ember.Object.create()
    }
}
```

From the route action I am want to modify the route model.employee. I tried the following, but I am not getting the object.

```
actions:{
    editAction : function(id) {
        var emp = this.get("model");
        console.log(emp.employee);

    }
}
```

Can anyone give a solution to get and modify model object(employee)?

Comment: `emp.get('employee');` and your employee isn't an instance of the employee model, if you want an empty employee model use `this.store.createRecord('employee', {});`

Comment: I tried emp.get('employee'), but is giving TypeError: emp.get is not a function

Comment: Miguel covered everything that needed to be covered ^^

Comment: Yes Kitler. It worked for me. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First problem is that you should return a promise from the model hook. That way, the transition will wait for the promise to Resolve. `return { /*...*/};` returns an object and not a promise, even if the object itself contains promises.
The solution is to use `Ember.RSVP.hash` like:

```
model() {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    employeeList: this.store.findAll('employee'),
    employee: Ember.Object.create()
  });
}
```

This will return a promise **that resolves when all inner promises resolve.**

---

The second problem is that you can't use `this.get('model')` in a route. If you think about it the `model` property is the hook itself and not the resolved model. Solutions:

1. That action is sent from the controller/template. Can't you pass the model as a parameter? That way you could access the model through the function arguments.
2. If you absolutely need to, `this.modelFor(this.routeName);` returns the model for the current route.
3. You can access the model in route through the controller like `this.controller.get('model')`.
4. You could also implement the [setupController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController) hook and access there the model. You can then do things like `this.set('employeeModel', model);` for later access.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.get('context')
```

gives you access to the model in the route action.